# Cloning a bios legacy Arch installation to an image file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to copy the used block of an Arch disk (legacy) to an image file.
The Arch installation is only on 1 partition 
dos, bootable 83, ext4

From a live cd:

```sh
// Mounting the disk to copy
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/source

// Getting the size of the used block and adding 0.6G
size=$(sudo df -h /mnt/USB | tail -1 | sed 's/  */ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f3 | sed 's/G//g')
size=$(echo "(${size} + 0.6)" | scale=0 bc)

// Creating an empty image file of the right size
fallocate -l ${size}G copy.img

// Creating the partition
sudo fdisk copy.img <<EOF
o
n
1


a
1
w
EOF

// Mounting the image to a loop device
sudo losetup -fP copy.img

// Formatting the partition
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1

// Mounting the partition
sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/destination

// Copying the files
sudo rsync -aHAX --info=progress2 /mnt/source/* /mnt/destination

// CD to destination && mounting dev/sys/run/proc
cd /mnt/destination
sudo mount -t proc /proc proc/; sudo mount --rbind /sys sys/; sudo mount --rbind /dev dev/; sudo mount --rbind /run run/

// Chrooting in the destination
disk=$disk loopDevice=$loopDevice sudo -E chroot /mnt/destination /bin/bash <<"EOT"
mount -a
oldUUID=$(lsblk -oNAME,UUID ${disk}1 | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
newUUID=$(lsblk -oNAME,UUID ${loopDevice}p1 | tail -1 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
sed -i "s/${oldUUID}/${newUUID}/g" /etc/fstab
sed -i "s/${oldUUID}/${newUUID}/g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-install ${loopDevice}
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
mkinitcpio -p linux
EOT

// Unmount disk
sudo umount /dev/source
sudo umount /dev/destination
```

I expect the image to be writable to a new disk and the new disk to be an exact same copy.

But I either get "no bootable disk detected" or the dreaful "Error: device 'UUID=XXXX' not found. Skipping fsck." even after a double check in /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/grub.cfg that the UUID is the right one..

I am stuck...

Comment: Consider [unix.se] for questions that are more about system administration than software development.

Comment: ...that said, honestly, if I were going to debug this, I'd want to logs for the boot process -- both from the kernel, and from the script itself.

Comment: You are right, I typed the code out of memory but after reading your comment, I looked at my gist and saw my error.  I edited my code with the real command.

Comment: Yup, post-edit this looks a lot more plausible. Still, though -- to debug this I'd be starting by getting some logs, even if it meant physically connecting a serial port and instrumenting the initrd to send xtrace logs through it (and passing a `console=` argument to the kernel to get dmesg content there as well). Just providing the code is pretty nearly asking for mind reading.

Comment: What kind of script is that?